# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am migrating my application from spring boot version 1.5x to 2.1.6.RELEASE and trying to deploy my app in WAS9. Getting below exception while starting the app :

nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader

Got to know that org.springframework.boot.env.**PropertySourcesLoader** doesnot exists in spring boot 2.0.

Can anyone please help me with the alternative to use if the above Class is decommisioned in Spring Boot 2.x.

Comment: What is you use case? Do you use `PropertySourcesLoader` to load property source manually?

Comment: Yeah, I am  using this in order to use **getAllFileExtensions();** method.

Comment: Yes, I am using that to load property source manually.